flutter : Change sound output device on android
I need a solution to connect to sound output devices (via Bluetooth or cable). I need to find and display their names, along with functionality for connecting, disconnecting, and detecting the current device. I've encountered the issue that there is no built-in feature in Android for this purpose, similar to AirPlay on iOS.
